Computing the DFT of three sine waves with Aliasing
I was asked to compute the DFT of the following:
$$x(t) = \sin(2 \pi 1000 t) + \sin(2 \pi 3500 t) + \sin(2 \pi 19000 t)$$
Sampled at $f_s = 20,000 [Hz]$ for $N=256$ samples.

can you please look at my calculation and see if it's accurate and whether there's a shorter method?
Trying to verify my answer with numpy gets me either errors or a plot with two peaks.
The computation
We use the fact that the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) samples the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) in the frequency domain. First, we sample the signal in the time domain:
$$t_n = \frac{n}{f_s}$$
$$x[n] = \sin\left(2 \pi \frac{1000n}{20000}\right) + \sin\left(2 \pi \frac{3500n}{20000}\right) + \sin\left(2 \pi \frac{19000n}{20000}\right), \quad 0 \leq n < N$$
To analyze the DTFT, we can write the signal as an infinite signal multiplied by a rectangular window (with $0 \leq n < N$), which introduces convolution in the frequency domain. However, for now, let’s focus on the infinite signal and apply the correction for finite length later.
We use the following formula for the DTFT of a sine wave:
$$\sin(\Omega_0 n) \to \frac{\pi}{j}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\Omega - \Omega_0 - 2 \pi k\right) - \delta\left(\Omega + \Omega_0 - 2 \pi k\right)\right\}$$
$$\sin\left(2 \pi \frac{1000n}{20000}\right) \to\frac{\pi}{j} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\Omega - 0.1\pi - 2 \pi k\right) - \delta\left(\Omega + 0.1\pi - 2 \pi k\right)\right\}$$
$$\sin\left(2 \pi \frac{3500n}{20000}\right) \to\frac{\pi}{j} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\Omega - \frac{7}{20}\pi - 2 \pi k\right) - \delta\left(\Omega + \frac{7}{20}\pi - 2 \pi k\right)\right\}$$
$$\sin\left(2 \pi \frac{19000n}{20000}\right) \to \frac{\pi}{j} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\Omega - 1.9\pi - 2 \pi k\right) - \delta\left(\Omega + 1.9\pi - 2 \pi k\right)\right\}$$
Since DTFT is defined over $\Omega \in [-\pi,\pi]$, we rewrite the third term for $\sin\left(2 \pi \frac{19000n}{20000}\right)$. Using the periodicity of the delta function:
$$\sin\left(2 \pi \frac{19000n}{20000}\right) \to \frac{\pi}{j} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\Omega + 0.1\pi - 2 \pi k\right) - \delta\left(\Omega - 0.1\pi - 2 \pi k\right)\right\}$$
Notice that the components at $\Omega = 0.1\pi$ cancel perfectly:
$$X(\Omega) = \frac{\pi}{j} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\Omega - \frac{7}{20}\pi - 2 \pi k\right) - \delta\left(\Omega + \frac{7}{20}\pi - 2 \pi k\right)\right\}$$
Since we are working with a finite-length signal (windowed by $N$), the rectangular window introduces convolution with a Dirichlet kernel:
$$S(\Omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} X(\Omega) * D(\Omega, N) = \frac{1}{2j} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left\{D\left(\Omega - \frac{7}{20}\pi - 2 \pi k, N\right) - D\left(\Omega + \frac{7}{20}\pi - 2 \pi k, N\right)\right\}$$
To compute the DFT, we sample the frequency domain representation:
$$S[k] = \frac{1}{2j} \left\{D\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N} - \frac{7}{20}\pi, N\right) - D\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N} + \frac{7}{20}\pi, N\right)\right\}$$
Plotting
I computed the Numerical FFT and plotted it with the following functions provided by my uni:
signal = np.sin(2*pi*f1*tvec)+np.sin(2*pi*f2*tvec)+np.sin(2*pi*f3*tvec)

signal_short = signal[:256]
fvec256 = create_freq_vector(256,20e3)
signalF256 = np.fft.fft(signal_short)[:signal_short.size//2] # Take only positive half
signalFdB256 = (np.abs(signalF256))
basic_plot(x=fvec256, y=signalFdB256,xlabel="Frequencies [Hz]", ylabel=R"$|X^F(f)|^{256}_{dB}$")


It would help if you defined $k$ or used another variable, as with the DFT $k$ is typically used as a single frequency bin in the DFT but it appears you are using it as the range of frequency bins within $f=[0, 2\pi)$. Also you should include the specific formula for your DFT as it appears you are using a scaled variant.

In this answer I derived a closed-form expression for the DFT of a discrete-time sinusoid. Since the DFT is linear you can just add up the expressions for the three sinusoids with different frequencies. I wouldn't take the detour via the DTFT.

Of course, the FFT is the fastest approach to compute the DFT, but if the intention was to analytically derive an equation for the expected result for these specific tones, the approach looks good including determining that the component at 1 KHz would cancel perfectly with the component at 19 KHz (which would alias to 1 KHz out of phase when the signal is sampled at 20 KHz).
The result will be simply the DFT of a 3.5 KHz sine wave sampled at 20 KHz.
I recommend not using $k$ as a range index since that is typically used as the frequency bin for the DFT, as in there are $k = 0 \ldots N-1$ frequency bins in the DFT. Further the DFT as used by the OP is a scaled version specifically given as:
$$X(k) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j k \omega_o n}$$
Where $\omega_o = 2 \pi /N$ radians/sample.
And $n$ indexes at the sampling rate such that $t = n/f_s$ with $f_s$ as the sampling rate in Hz and $t$ is the continuous time domain in seconds.
The scaling is a good approach if we want to use the DTFT of an infinite duration sinusoid and then use the property that the "DFT is a sampled version of the DTFT" after convolving with the Dirichlet Kernel from the finite time duration window. (The easier way however would be to define it over the finite frequency range of $0$ to $2\pi$ and use circular convolution). Continuing with the OP's approach this would be:
$$X[k\omega_o] = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{-j k \omega_o n}$$
Where in the limit $k\omega_o$ becomes a continuous function of $\omega$ to give us $X(\omega)$.
The solution to this is clearer by observing that the sine itself will have two tones in the frequency domain as given by Euler's formula: $\sin(2\pi 3500 t) = \frac{1}{2j}e^{j2\pi 3500 t} - \frac{1}{2j}e^{-j2\pi 3500 t}$, such that with the Fourier Transform each $e^{j\omega t}$ is a single impulse in frequency, and once sampled becomes periodic in frequency at multiples of the sampling rate.
Note how for a single exponential frequency tone at $\omega_1 \in [0, 2\pi)$, the DTFT as define above would be:
$$\text{DTFT}(e^{j\omega_1 n}) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{j\omega_1 n})e^{-j k \omega_o n} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \delta(\omega - \omega_1 - 2 \pi m)$$
Thus the DTFT of a sine wave would be in this case:
$$\sin(\omega_o n) \to \frac{1}{2j}\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \left\{\delta\left(\omega - \omega_1 - 2 \pi m\right) - \delta\left(\omega + \omega_1 - 2 \pi m\right)\right\}$$
The OP should be able to proceed from there toward the solution as the convolution with the Dirichlet Kernel.
For verification, below is the Python code and plot for the magnitude expected result using the same scaling (Note the magnitude of 0.5 for each of the two tones consistent with Euler's formula as introduced):

Python code:
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import scipy.fft as fft
nsamps = 256
fs = 20000
t = np.arange(nsamps)/fs
out = np.sin(2*np.pi*1000*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*3500*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*19000*t)
dftout = 1/nsamps * fft.fft(out)


Thank you for your answer Dan! I'll amend my computation. Could you please elaborate further on why you're taking the limit of the samples as $N \to \infty$ in this equation: $$X[k\omega_o] = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{-j k \omega_o n}$$. As for the simpler approach, do you suggest working directly with the DFT transform?

@Piratemetaldrinkingcrew: I don't know what Dan would suggest, but I'm sure that there is no advantage in working with the DTFT. Just apply the formula for the DFT. See my comment under the question.

Yes I agree with Matt- working with the DFT directly is simpler. The DTFT provides additional insights that may have helped your overall understanding. As for the limit question it is because you wanted to use the DTFT of an infinitely long sinusoid in time. If you don't scale by N and take the limit the result does not converge (and with the limit it converges to the dirac delta that you used and the frequency domain converges to the continuous function).
